# Match two lines in a big log file and display the content between them

Tags: python, regex, perl, awk, sed

I have a big log file that has many things going on. What is required is to fetch the content in between two lines in the log file.

Example:

```
----------------------------------------
-- ServiceDataBlock (SDB):{MO}:
  > From channel# ..... [111]
  > (Orig)Ton, TP_OA .. [91][1234567891234]
  > (Dest)Ton, TP_DA .. [A0][12345]
  > TP_PID, TP_DCS .... [00][00]
  > TP_SCTS ........... []
  > TP_UserDataHdr .... []
  > TP_UserData ....... {3}[yes]
----------------------------------------
```

The content between line `-- ServiceDataBlock (SDB):{MO}:` and `> TP_UserData ....... {3}[yes]` is dynamic.

I want to fetch only `(Orig)Ton, TP_OA .. [91][1234567891234]` and `TP_UserData ....... {3}[yes]` in between :-)

Please note there are many other things their that has same `-- ServiceDataBlock (SDB):{MO}:` defined, but does not have `TP_UserData ....... {3}[yes]` in the block.

Can somebody help? I tried using regex, grep, sed and awk.

I need the output in either CSV or Excel format.

Comment: Well, Regex would be a good choice and I'm sure it would work. Can you paste your Regex which you tried? (This is how the site works - we don't provide code, we want you to learn.) Also, please specify the language, as regex differs language to language.

Comment: You could start with extracting all service data blocks from the log file.. show us the code you used..

Comment: does `TP_UserData` only appear where you want it?

Comment: Please choose a language first, try yourself and then if have any problem, just post your question here.

Comment: Not very clear about what to treat. I imagina that label of line is always de same (if present due to your dynamic remark) but not the value associate. Block separator are `----`for the end. Give a bigger sample and result expected with it

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple state-based parser. It is not well-tested and may make some assumptions about the format of the log file which are incorrect. It should help you get started, though.

```
def process_log(path):
    contents = []
    with open(path) as stream:
        state = 0
        line = ''
        block = None
        while line is not None:
            try:
                if not line:
                    line = next(stream)
            except StopIteration:
                line = None
            else:
                line = line.strip()
                if state == 0:
                    if line.startswith('-- ServiceDataBlock'):
                        block = []
                        state = 1
                    line = ''
                    continue
                elif state >= 1:
                    if line.startswith('>'):
                        line = line.lstrip('> ')
                        if not line.startswith('From channel#'):
                            block.append(line)
                            if line.startswith('TP_UserData '):
                                state = 2
                        line = ''
                        continue
            if state == 2:
                contents.append(block)
            state = 0
    return contents
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys.

I understand that i am not expected for a ready code here :-)

Following is what i have achieved using grep :-)

```
grep -Po "(.*Orig.*\[(234.*)\])\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*yes.*)" filename
```

This would actually help me get the data, I have do it more for to get the exact stuff but this works for now.

I will post the complete answer when this is done.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A perl way:

```
perl -ane 'print if /-- ServiceDataBlock/ .. /TP_UserData /' filename
```